# Is there an endpoint to batch get urn:li:digitalmediaAsset in the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are doing a `rest/posts?author={MY_ORG}` request against the LinkedIn Api (version 202211). Some of the posts returned contain content referenced with `urn:li:digitalmediaAsset` for which we need the download URL.

When I encounter `urn:li:image` or `urn:li:video` I can do a BATCH get to fetch additional details about the assets. I'd like to do the same thing for `urn:li:digitalmediaAsset`. I haven't seen an endpoint for that - does it exist?

I understand, that I can use a `projection` here but, I'd like to align with the code that I have for images and videos if the endpoint exists. In other words, I am looking for an alternative to using projections.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the id you get for a digitalmediaAsset is actually the same as for an image asset. So if you have id `urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:D4E0BAQGlt8Ay_jA` you can replace the `digitalmediaAsset`-part with `image` (resulting in `urn:li:image:D4E0BAQGlt8Ay_jA`) and then use the Image API to retrieve the actual downloadUrl.

I haven't tested this with videos yet. But I thought I'd share this before I forget.